# Device lists as unauthorized using adb connect

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb

On a remote machine I boot an emulator

```
emulator -avd emu1 -ports 5555,5554
```

and on local machine I connect to emulator

```
adb connect 10.9.1.6:5555
```

then I use adb devices to list device, but device is unauthorized

```
List of devices attached
10.9.1.6:5555   offline
```

Moreover, when I connect, there is no dialog requesting debug permission confirmation on device screen.

I have fiddled with revoking debug perms with no results. I have tried a couple device models. I am using Android Q.

Maybe I should try a lower API, but I would like to use Android Q.

I was also thinking of trying with a root-able (non production) device.

Answer (score 0):

make sure your USB Debugging is ON from the Developer option.

Comment: I did, and it's on data transfer

Answer (score 0):

I booted an emu with an architecture image which does not have Google play, and the device listed as authorized after connecting to it with `adb connect`, so I think I've solved my problem: don't use a production emulator.